# can sampling remove the limitations in greedy algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sampling, greedy

knowing this is a vague question, but i just want to know that, given the limitations of greedy (i.e., not always finding the optimal solution), does sampling the data space in a randomized manner or some structured manner reduce or remove the limitations of greedy algorithm.

i understand the answer to this is problem specific, but given a problem that shows the limitation of greedy algorithm can sampling be used in any way in order to guide the greedy algorithm to generate an optimal solution?

many thanks in advance.

Comment: Seeing its such a general question I think that it is probably better to ask it on another SO site.  I don't know the subject matter, but off the top of my head http://cstheory.stackexchange.com or http://cs.stackexchange.com might be better places

Comment: ok i'll post it there too, thank you

Comment: Crossposted and answered at http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/40430